# How to Redirect URL in Azure front door with 'OR' condition?

Tags: azure, redirect, azure-front-door

I want to implement about 300 redirects on Azure Front Door. All redirect URLs are in a csv file. How can I use the PowerShell command to read from csv file and apply all redirects without manually creating rules one by one? (if it's possible)

The other question is, how can I apply Ruleset with `OR IF` condition? The condition available in Front Door is only `AND IF`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`Azure Front Door` does not support `OR IF` condition in the `Rules engine Configuration` as of now.

The available condition as of now is `AND`.

When we try to add multiple conditions, it will be taken as `AND IF` by default.

[image]

> how can I apply Ruleset with `OR IF` condition

We can achieve this by creating multiple rules with different conditions, the backend pool has to be same for both the rules.

- If any of the condition specified in the rules are satisfied, then the request will be redirected to the same backend pool.

> How can I use the PowerShell command to read from csv file and apply all redirects without manually creating rules one by one?

- Yes, we can use `Powershell` module to automate the process and read `URL's` from csv file and apply redirects.

Install the `Azure Powershell` Module and connect to the Azure Subscription.

```cs
Install-Module -Name Az
Connect-AzAccount
```

Import the [csv](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv?view=powershell-7.3) file

```cs
$redirects = Import-Csv -Path "C:\****\URL.csv"
```

[image]

As mentioned in the MSDoc,Use [New-AzFrontDoorRulesEngine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.frontdoor/new-azfrontdoorrulesengine?view=azps-9.5.0).

```cs
foreach ($rdt in $redirects)
{  
    New-AzFrontDoorRulesEngine -FrontDoor HarshuFD -Name $rdt.Name  
}
```